# Cannot see jacoco task when executing sbt tasks command (-v is tried as well)

Tags: scala, sbt, jacoco

I was trying to use jacoco to integrate test report to my sbt project. https://github.com/sbt/jacoco4sbt

I added `jacoco.settings` into `build.sbt`

I also added `addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.1.6")` into `plugins.sbt`

When I run `sbt jacoco:check`, it is working fine. However, when I try to look at how many tasks for jacoco, `sbt tasks` doesn't show anything related to jacoco.

I have to go to source code to look at it.

https://github.com/sbt/jacoco4sbt/blob/master/src/main/scala/de/johoop/jacoco4sbt/Keys.scala

May I know why jacoco is not shown for `sbt tasks` command and what is preferable way to look at all the available tasks for the plugins

**Edit:**

I suspect that the statement `lazy val Config = config("jacoco") extend(Test) hide` means jacoco extends Test task, so it wont show it in the sbt tasks, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running

```
> tasks -v
```

> Edit: If that doesn't work consider adding more "v"s, such as `tasks -vvv`, or even `tasks -V` to see all the tasks.

I see, for instance, `cover`:

```
This is a list of tasks defined for the current project.
It does not list the scopes the tasks are defined in; use the 'inspect' command for that.
Tasks produce values.  Use the 'show' command to run the task and print the resulting value.

  check                  Executes the tests and saves the execution data in 'jacoco.exec'.
  classesToCover         compiled classes (filtered by includes and excludes) that will be covered
  clean                  Cleaning JaCoCo's output-directory.
  compile                Compiles sources.
  console                Starts the Scala interpreter with the project classes on the classpath.
  consoleProject         Starts the Scala interpreter with the sbt and the build definition on the classpath and useful imports.
  consoleQuick           Starts the Scala interpreter with the project dependencies on the classpath.
  copyResources          Copies resources to the output directory.
  cover                  Executes the tests and creates a JaCoCo coverage report.
  coveredSources         Covered Sources.
```

Note also what it says at the beginning (wrapped for clarity):

```
It does not list the scopes the tasks are defined in;
  use the 'inspect' command for that.
```

which leads to

```
> inspect cover
[info] No entry for key.
[info] Description:
[info]  Executes the tests and creates a JaCoCo coverage report.
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:cover
[info]  {.}/*:cover
[info]  */*:cover
[info] Related:
[info]  jacoco:cover
```

So you know to run `jacoco:cover`

Comment: the tasks -v show jacoco tasks in pure sbt project, but it doesnt show anything in play framework project. but thanks for the answer

Comment: @Cloudtech I see what you mean. I've added details about how to see it in a simple play app.